# Which version to install on macbook pro

Tags: installation, macbook-pro

I'm new to Ubuntu, I really want to check it out but i'm having a bit of trouble, hopefully y'all can help me out.

I have a Macbook Pro mid-2010 version. I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit version, and then burned it

Comment: Are you having trouble live booting Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit on your MacBook Pro? Chuck the disc in and hold down the C during boot. You'll then have the option to boot into Ubuntu 13.04 and you can try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the standard 64 bit version of Ubuntu. The later the greater especially since you have such a modern MacBook.

I do recommend that you run your computer in EFI mode though. Since it will allow you to use the features of your MacBook Pro to the fullest,

Like Switching between the two graphics cards  (in default bios mode you will use the powerhungry card by default) Beter Disk performance since [AHCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) is enabled in efi mode.

This means that you should install [refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) **before** actually installing Ubuntu your MacBook. Look around askubuntu for a more detailed instruction regarding efi/refit and installing on Mac